# asp.net - date - date format changes in server

Tags: asp.net, sql, date

I have a code in asp.net, where the user enters the date selection throught an AJAX calendar pop-up control as per below:

```html
<td class="style14">
<asp:TextBox ID="DateSelection" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="90px"
AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDateSelection" runat="server" Height="22px" 
ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.jpg" Width="19px" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderDateSelection" runat="server" 
Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageButtonDateSelection" 
PopupPosition="BottomRight" TargetControlID="DateSelection" 
FirstDayOfWeek="Monday">
</asp:CalendarExtender></td>
```

From SQL I pickup the date and use it in the SQL code as follows:

```
declare @dt datetime 
set @dt = convert(datetime,'" & DateSelection.Text & "',104
```

All is well in my remote desktop, but when I publish the site it doent' work due to diferent date formats on server.

I can not figure out what format the server has, but I'm wondering if there is a fool proof way to work with any date format, so that I can develop on my pc with my date format and send the code safely to the server and warantee that it will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all** you can check what is the dateformat setting for your connecdtion on that server by [DBCC USEROPTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180065%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

Output:

```
Set Option  Value
----------------------
...
language    us_english
dateformat  mdy         <---
datefirst   7
...
```

**Second** you can change date format for your connection using [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
```

**Third** and you can always use SQL/ISO date format which is `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME 
SET @dt = CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-03-09')
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the culture property as : - <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/User/MainMaster.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MemberRegistration.aspx.cs" Inherits="HO_MemberRegistration" Culture="en-gb" %>